# Como puedes alternar comentarios de diferente codigo en un mismo archivo en VISUAL STUDIO CODE

Tags: vscode

Para hacer comentarios de línea, seleccionas lo que quieres comentar, después CTRL+} y aparecen caracteres de comentario de línea.

Pero dependen de la extensión del archivo y no del código seleccionado, hay manera que dependiendo del código seleccionado ponga el o los caracteres que se necesitan para el comentario.

Es decir para:

javascript //
para php //
para html 
para asp '

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: o sea.. tu pregunta es... que extension debo instalar para que segun el tipo de archivo ponga el tipo de ocmentario que corresponde??? porque vscode es solo un editor de texto.. no hace nada si no tiene la extension correspondiente... Y si esa es la pregunta, entonces va a terminar cerrada, porque aca no recomendamos extensiones ni nada de eso...